# Why is JsonConvert.Deserialize() not parsing to the object it was serialised from?

Tags: c#, json

I'm just exploring NewtonSoft - Why doesn't this work?

```
var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MethodThatProducesGameInstance());
var y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x);
Game g = (Game)y; // Error here
```

I can't serialize a `Game` object to a string and then deserialize the string back to a `Game` object - I thought that was the whole point of converting to and from Json? What am I missing?

My Game object is like so:

```
public class Game
{
    public Game()
    {
        Moves = new HashSet<Move>();
        GameHasPlayers = new HashSet<GameHasPlayer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Move> Moves { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GameHasPlayer> GameHasPlayers { get; set; }
}
```

and the JSON produced from it into `var x` is like this:

```
"{\"Id\":3,\"DateCreated\":\"2019-11-13T14:31:54.303\",\"Comment\":\"First test game\",\"Moves\":[],\"GameHasPlayers\":[]}"
```

Comment: What is you game object look like?

Comment: Not every object is serializable.  What is this `Game` object?

Comment: have you tried explicitly deserializing to a game object instead of .net object? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(x);`

Comment: Okay, most of the types in your `Game` object can be serialized.  What are `GameHasPlayer` and `Move`?

Comment: @Klaycon that did it, I knew my game object wasn't too complex for it, I just thought I had to `Cast` my object but putting it here works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x);` with no generic type parameter will just deserialize it to the `Object` base class, which cannot be cast to a class deriving from it since it wasn't created as one.

Instead, pass the method a [type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) like this: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(x);` to explicitly tell the deserializer to create an instance of `Game`.

Comment: Will accept in 6 minutes! I dunno what `<>` symbols mean calling a method like this, but it looks and acts like how I imagined the `Cast` to work so this is exactly what I needed and works perfect.

Comment: Feel free to peruse the C# Programming Guide's [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) on generic type parameters if you'd like to understand what `<Game>` means and why it solved the problem.